# How to get cat pee smell out of a camera

Tags: cleaning, pets

Yes, you read it right!  I was staying with friends and their rotten little furball peed in my handbag.  Anything soft, like my cloth wallet, was a write-off.  Anything hard, like keys, just needed a good rinse with soap.  But I don’t know what to do about my camera.  It was in its case so escaped any real damage and it still works fine.  But it smells terrible and I’m not sure what’s the safest way to clean it without damaging it.

Comment: Cat pee is the worst.  Had to rip up an entire floor and 2 ft of drywall to try and get rid of the smell in one room.  What kind of camera is it?  Some types might allow for removal of the shell, which could be soaked or treated more harshly than the whole device.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is Electrical Cleaner that is a solvent used to clean electronics without risking damage by corrosion.

However, before processing with that route... I would advise to wipe the external shell of your camera as much as you possibly can to make sure you haven't missed a spot of residue. It does not take much urine to have a strong smell stick to your camera (clean cracks and crevices)

If the problem still persist, you may need to take the camera apart (or to camera shop) and have them clean it with solvent used for electrical components. Look up "Electrical cleaner" in google to find many useful products with reviews.

Comment: It might be safe to put the camera in a container with household ammonia (dilute ammonium hydroxide), **but not in contact with the liquid**, for a few minutes to see if the ammonia reacts with the odorant. If that doesn't help, you could try vinegar. Don't leave it for too long, though.

Comment: Urine contains ammonia already.  It takes vinegar to counteract ammonia smells.

Comment: These chemicals could damage the camera beyond repair.